# vb.net read mysql table columns no matter what field type in mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i am runnig this code inside a reader loop:

```
While reader.read
For x = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
    MsgBox(reader.GetValue(x))
    Dim find_text As String = "<<" & reader.GetName(x) & ">>"
    Dim replacet_text As String = reader.GetString(x)

    oDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:=find_text, ReplaceWith:=replacet_text, Replace:=word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
Next
End While
```

so its showing every column as my SQL query says `SELECT * from table1`

but the issue is, depending on the type of column in the database its showing errors like `cannot be converted to type 'String'.`

how can i do ALL columns no matter what type? i just want to read all into a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Dim replacet_text As String = reader.GetValue(x).ToString` and if it failed it means the type is not convertible to string so you can place this line of code in a try catch block and place error message when data is not convertible to string:

```
While reader.read
For x = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
    MsgBox(reader.GetValue(x))
    Dim find_text As String = "<<" & reader.GetName(x) & ">>"
    Dim replacet_text As String
    Try
        replacet_text = reader.GetValue(x).ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        replacet_text = "-- Not Available! --"
    End Try
    oDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:=find_text, ReplaceWith:=replacet_text, Replace:=word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
Next
End While
```

Comment: Is there a way I can check the type of column in the loop ?

Comment: Yes you can use `reader.GetSchemaTable()` function to access information about requested table type in another DataTable which is called `Schema Table`. The first column(index 0) in schema table should be your field name and second column wil be the type. And number of rows in schema table are equal to number of table defined fields.